# Hiding an imageView using a button in another ViewController Swift XCode

Tags: ios, swift

I need to hide an ImageView in ViewControllerTwo using a button from ViewControllerOne in Swift.

how can i use "imageView.hidden = true" in another ViewController ?

Any help please ? Thanks

Comment: you can simply pass a flag in another view controller using preopareforsegue and make imageview hidden.

Comment: please check the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your button function (in viewController1):

```
@IBAction func yourButtonFunction(_ sender: AnyObject){
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(true, forKey: "isImageHidden")
}
```

And in viewController2, add this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(){
     super.viewDidAppear(true)
     if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isImageHidden") != nil{
          let condition = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isImageHidden") as! Bool
          if condition{
              //should be hidden
              self.imageView.isHidden = true
              UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isImageHidden")
          }
     }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It works perfectly for me, there is nothing related to my code that isn't working. I do not know what you are doing in your project, but I don't think it's my fault

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to alter one view controller's views from another view controller. That's bad design. Instead you should make the view controller whose image you want to hide have a delegate property. Create a delegate protocol that defines a message the other view controller calls. This is a very common design pattern, and one you should learn.

There are a lot of tutorials online showing the delegate design pattern.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it more complicated to use Delegates instead of Global variables or UserDefaults? What are the advantages of Delegates when you have easier techniques?

Comment: Global variables are a bad idea. They tightly couple your components together, limiting reusability. UserDefaults is a "heavy" solution unless you need persistence between launches of your app.

Comment: Yes, using delegates is more work, but it makes for a cleaner, more modular, more reusable design.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!